# PHP code to display current date infor only from SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have the following PHP code that calls info from the SQL database. Currently I am showing only X amount of lines from the SQL. But I would like to show only the current date's info on the SQL query

```
 SELECT * FROM e_track_access_log WHERE member_id>0 AND ORDER BY datetime_accessed DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Is what I currently have. I need to only display the current date in this PHP screen.

I know it would be AND in the query but not sure how to tell the code what I want. As the following problem I have is that the table datetime_accessed is in Date / Time format: 2013-08-11 01:30:53

Comment: Which RDBMS you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for **[GETDATE ( )](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx)**

```
SELECT * FROM e_track_access_log WHERE member_id>0 
AND datetime_accessed < GETDATE ( ) ORDER BY datetime_accessed DESC LIMIT 0,10
```